# import variable (not function) from dll to C#

Tags: c#, dll

I have a Dll created in C which exports some global variables (int and char[]).
I already know how to do this for functions (with DllImport), but I can't find any C# example for variables.

Comment: this MSDN thread contains an example of accessing variables: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb975f44-dd2d-462f-8dd4-bf7bb938108d/how-do-i-import-a-variable-that-is-exported-from-unmanaged-dll?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: In c language variables  in the parameter list are placed on the execution stack and when returning from the dll the stack is popped.  So the variables are no longer valid.  So the memory for the variables in the parameter list either has to be allocated before calling the dll, or the dll has to use a windows allocation method to get the memory for the variables.